# Using nvidia-settings over ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11, nvidia

Now the new nvidia-driver has implemented CoolBits for the newer graphics cards I'm attempting to control fan/clock speed over ssh.

When attempting to run anything with nvidia-settings via ssh I get errors like the following:

```
user@system:~$ nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUOverclockingState=1
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.
user@system:~$ nvidia-settings -q GPU3DClockFreqs
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.
```

Is this due to the Xorg server not starting up (No monitor plugged in) and nvidia can't hook into the Xorg's current graphics card?

Is there a way to specify the GPU nvidia-settings uses?

```
user@system:~$ nvidia-settings -v
nvidia-settings:  version 337.19  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-04)
Tue Apr 29 20:12:23 PDT 2014
  The NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.

  This program is used to configure the NVIDIA Linux graphics driver.
  For more detail, please see the nvidia-settings(1) man page.

  Copyright (C) 2004 - 2010 NVIDIA Corporation.

user@system:~$ uname -a
Linux system 3.2.0-64-generic-pae #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 22:22:15 UTC 2014 i686 i686 >i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what's the role of SSH in all this? Do you want to act on the machine where the SSH client is running, or on the machine where the SSH server is running? Is an X server running on that machine?

Comment: I am using SSH to access the machine on which I would like to play with the nvidia-settings, which is also the SSH server. The last question is one I thought I asked. If the Linux machine (SSH server) boots with no monitor plugged in, does this cause the X server to be omitted. Hence why nvidia-settings cannot find the card. Is there a way to specify the GPU nvidia-settings uses when no X server is running? `ps -A | grep 'x\|X'` shows no X server. Also the $DISPLAY variable is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. If you're not running X on a Nvidia device, you can't manage the Nvidia driver. You can verify this by running `echo $DISPLAY`. It should be `:0`, but X forwarding will change that to something else. I believe it might run another X server just for forwarding.